# How to "freeze" GLIBC version with conda?

Tags: python, conda, glibc

I routinely use conda environments on Linux. 
Now I need to create an environment for a Linux with GLIBC 2.5. I can get an official version of miniconda using GLIBC 2.5 but (as far as I know) nothing guarantees the packages I will install do not require GLIBC version higher than 2.5.
Is there any way I can constrain or know what are the packages GLIBC requirements?